# Strange behavior with cursor position while deleting with libPhoneNumber-iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, phone-number, formatter, libphonenumber

I using library [libPhoneNumber-iOS](https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS)  for formatting phone numbers in my app.

When I deleting text from the end of the text field, all works fine, but if the cursor is in the middle of a text field when I delete "-" char, cursor jumping to the end of a text field.

[image]

How I can fix this?

Thanks.

**UPD**

Chunk of code:

```
- (void)inputText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSString *numberWithCode = [self stringWithPhoneCodeFromString:text];
    self.text = PVNumberFormattingEnabled? [self.formatter inputString:numberWithCode] : numberWithCode;
}

- (NSString *)stringWithPhoneCodeFromString:(NSString *)string
{
    if ( [string isEqualToString:_countryModel.phoneCode] || DEVICE_IS_IPAD )
    {
        return string;
    }

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", _countryModel.phoneCode? : @"", string? : @""];
}

- (void)phoneNumberTextDidChange
{
    NSString *normalizedText = [self deletePhoneCodeFromText:self.text];

    if ( phoneNumberUtil && normalizedText != nil)
    {
        normalizedText = [phoneNumberUtil normalize:normalizedText];
    }

    [self inputText:normalizedText];
}
```

But strange behaviour appears when someone trying to edit **selectedTextRange** at text field. When I added implement **setSelectedTextRange:**, I can't catch any calls, but whatever, cursor jumping to the end.

Comment: Can you provide the code that applies formatting behaviour to the textfield?

Comment: @mas'an I added code and some info

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't do C programming so I can't provide code examples, but can explain why the issue is happening and a possible solution as I've dealt with this same issue in Javascript.

This is due to the entire field's contents changing whenever one character is changed, which triggers a re-render and places the cursor at the end of the text string.

As far as solutions, you'd need to manually track and place the cursor yourself, and force it to remain where it should be.